# How can I change this block of code to return only records associated with a specific ID.?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I’m trying to create a query that returns records associated with one person’s id.

I’ve tried this:

```
viewModel.Students = db.Students.Where(sd => sd.StudentID==9);
```

but I don’t know how to cast it to my `InstructorIndexData()` or whether I even should do it that way.  How can I change this block of code to return only student with `id==9`?

```
var viewModel2 = new InstructorIndexData();
viewModel.Courses = viewModel.Instructors.Where(
    i => i.InstructorID == 2).Single().Courses               

viewModel.Enrollments = viewModel.Courses.Where(
    x => x.CourseID == 600).Single().Enrollments;

viewModel2.Students = db.Students.Where(sd => sd.StudentID==9);
return View(viewModel);
```

**Instructor Index Data:**

```
public class InstructorIndexData
{
    public IEnumerable<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Assignment> Assignments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what InstructorIndexData looks like?

Comment: I added InstructorIndexData the original post.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get?

Comment: When this view model loads it loads all students that are in this teacher's class and the same course.  I want to use the same model to further filter down to a specific student.

Comment: Is there anyway i can cast my result to my viewmodel something like... InstructorDataIndex newQuery = InstructorDataIndex<someQueryResult>?

Comment: I'm still a little confused. InstructorIndexData contains an IEnumerble<Student> already. What do you need cast for?